# DRF loses CSRF token with PUT method

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I have a regular `ModelViewSet`in my project, and it works perfectly with `GET` and `POST` requests, but it fails with `PUT`, returning this error:

```
{
    "detail": "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."
}
```

This is my **urls.py**:

```
from django.urls            import path,re_path,include
from django.utils.text      import slugify,camel_case_to_spaces
from PaymentsManagerApp     import views, models
from rest_framework         import routers

APP_NAME = 'PaymentsManagerApp'
router = routers.DefaultRouter()

router.register(r'payments', views.PaymentViewSet)

payments_list = views.PaymentViewSet.as_view({
    'get':'list',
    'post':'create'
})

payment_detail = views.PaymentViewSet.as_view({
'get':'retrieve',
'put':'update',
'patch':'partial_update',
'delete':'destroy'
```

})

```
def urlpattern_from_route(route):
    if "regex" in route and route['regex']:
        path_method = re_path
    else:
        path_method = path
    return path_method(route['path'],route['view'].as_view(),name=route['name'] if "name" in route else None)

routes_views = list(map(urlpattern_from_route,routes))
route_services = [

payment_detail = views.PaymentViewSet.as_view({
    'get':'retrieve',
    'put':'update',
    'patch':'partial_update',
    'delete':'destroy'
})

route_services = [
    path('payments/', payments_list, name='rest_payments_list'),
    path('payments/<int:pk>/', payment_detail, name='rest_payment_detail'),
]

urlpatterns = routes_views + route_services
```

This is my **views.py**:

```
import os
import json
from datetime                           import datetime, timedelta
from django.shortcuts                   import render
from PaymentsManagerApp                 import urls, models, serializers
from FrontEndApp                        import urls as Fronturls
from django.shortcuts                   import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth.mixins         import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.views.generic               import View
from django.contrib.auth.models         import Permission
from GeneralApp.utils                   import get_catalogs
from django.contrib.staticfiles         import finders
from django.utils.text                  import slugify,camel_case_to_spaces
from rest_framework                     import viewsets, permissions
from rest_framework.response            import Response
from django_filters.rest_framework      import DjangoFilterBackend
from rest_framework.response            import Response
from rest_framework.filters             import OrderingFilter, SearchFilter
from django.db.models                   import Q

class PaymentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        exclude_from_schema = True

        permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
        queryset = models.Payment.objects.all()
        serializer_class = serializers.PaymentSerializer
        filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, SearchFilter, OrderingFilter,)
        search_fields = ('payment_type', 'creation_user__username', 'provider__name', 'invoice', 'payment_method_type', 'payment_document_number')
        filter_fields = ('id', 'payment_type', 'creation_user', 'provider', 'is_payment_requested', 'is_paid', 'payment_method_type')
```

When I send a GET or a POST to `payments_manager/payments/`, it works perfectly. Also when I send a GET to `pyments_manager/payments/<int:pk>/`it works well.

The problem is when I send a PUT to `payments_manager/payments/<int:pk>/`, because I get the following:

[image]

I don't know why but DRF loses the logged user information (you can see the **log in** label, instead of the username).

**EDIT**

This is my REST_FRAMEWORK in **settings.py**:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ('rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ('django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',),
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 20,
    'DEFAULT_METADATA_CLASS': 'rest_framework.metadata.SimpleMetadata'
}
```

**EDIT**
I found that the error rises only if I access the endpoint directly from the browser using DRF default interfase (`127.0.0.1:8000/es/payments_manager/payments/1/`):
[image]

My PUT requests work perfectly from my javascript ajax.

Comment: Did you solve your issue? If so, what was it?

Comment: @JavierBuzzi No, i didn't. I found that the problem is only with DRF default interfase. My ajax from javascript still work perfectly without any change.

Comment: Can you describe the issue a bit better. What does "I found that the problem is only with DRF default interfase." mean?

Comment: @JavierBuzzi I added the explanation to the body of the question

Comment: I added TEMPLATES to my example, and tried PUTing to an existing record using the browser, and everything updates as expected (see my answer for details). Please provide django, drf, openapi???? swagger???? versions.

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: @JavierBuzzi as I told you, my endpoints work well with my front end as they are, just as your templates. The problem only rises when I use DRF default interfase.

Comment: I am using Django==2.05 and DRF==3.8.2. It was working well, in fact it works well in other machines. I am trying to find out if I installed something lately that caused the problem.

Comment: I really suggest you use docker, it has the advantage that anything you install on your host for any reason, wont interfere with anything else. I’ve tested all i could, with the information you’ve provided, you’re going to have to start isolating code and keep testing until it gets fixed, then you’ll know what is breaking it. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In order for to use session auth AND do a `POST` (is a little weird) / `PUT` / `PATCH` / `DELETE` / etc. you MUST pass a header.

see: https://github.com/django/django/blob/8b3f1c35dd848678225e8634d6880efeeab5e796/django/middleware/csrf.py#L306

I also created a little test for you:

https://gist.github.com/kingbuzzman/20dffbc34d22a899661ac3c065e3f747#file-django_rest_framework_session_vs_token-py-L209

```
  response = self.client.post('/session-login/', data={'username': 'user', 'password': 'pass'})
  self.assertEqual(302, response.status_code)
  self.assertIn('csrftoken', response.cookies)
  self.assertIn('sessionid', response.cookies)

  # Don't want to go through the trouble of having to get the CSRF from the login form
  self.client.handler.enforce_csrf_checks = True

  csrftoken = self.client.cookies.get('csrftoken').value

  # NOTE: The only reason this works it's because we're passing a header along with the request.
  response = self.client.patch('/payments/%s/' % (self.payment.id), content_type='application/json',
                               data=json.dumps({'is_paid': 'Y'}), HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN=csrftoken)
  self.assertEqual(200, response.status_code)
  self.assertEqual('Y', response.json()['is_paid'])

  # NOTE: The reason this DOES NOT works it's because we're NOT passing a header along with the request.
  response = self.client.patch('/payments/%s/' % (self.payment.id), content_type='application/json',
                               data=json.dumps({'is_paid': 'N'}))
  self.assertEqual(403, response.status_code)
```

**Edit.**

Added a user, logged in, navigated to `localhost/payments/` and added a record, then went to the record `localhost/payments/1/` and updated it (`PUT`). Everything works. Please add your django/drf versions.

[image]